# About a definition for an inner product in linear algebra books.

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, inner-products

I am reading a linear algebra book.

The typical definition of an inner product is the following:

> Let $F=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.
> Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$. An inner product on $V$ is a function that assigns, to every ordered pair of vectors $x$ and $y$ in $V$, a scalar in $F$, denoted $\langle x,y\rangle$, such that for all $x,y$, and $z$ in $V$ and all $c$ in $F$, the following hold:
> (a) $\langle x+z,y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle+\langle z,y\rangle.$
> (b) $\langle cx,y\rangle=c\langle x,y\rangle$.
> (c) $\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}=\langle y,x\rangle$, where the bar denotes complex conjugation.
> (d) If $x\neq 0$, then $\langle x, x\rangle$ is a positive real number.

Linear algebra books don't adopt the following definition for an inner product.
Why?
Isn't this definition ok?
I like this definition.

> Let $F=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.
> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$.
> Let $B=\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$.
> We define a function $f_B$ from $V\times V$ to $F$ by $f_B(v,w):=x_1\overline{y_1}+\dots+x_n\overline{y_n}$, where $v=x_1v_1+\dots+x_nv_n$ and $w=y_1v_1+\dots+y_nv_n$.
> $g$ is called an inner product on $V$ if $g=f_B$ for some basis $B$ of $V$.

Comment: Because the first definition is broader and works for abstract vector spaces of infinite dimension

Comment: @DougM Thank you very much for your comment. But many authors of linear algebra books write only about finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @tchappyha The fact that your definition is equivalent to the first one for finite dimensional spaces is a non-trivial fact based on the diagonalizability of hermitian matrices. The authors have probably concluded that showing that they are equivalent at this stage is not useful, and thus have chosen the first definition.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Your definition is fine, but to my mind would be better stated as a theorem that follows from the more abstract definition (indeed, it is a special case of Sylvester's law of inertia). What do you consider the strengths of your definition?

Comment: e.g. $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(t)g(t) \ dt$ is an inner product on the space of continuous functions.

Comment: Even if we talk about finite dimensional spaces, the first definition looks easier to work with. This is a general definition which works only with the space $V$, and doesn't force us to choose a basis.

Comment: Also from the second definition $\langle x,y \rangle = \lambda_1 x_1 \bar y_1 + \lambda_2 x_2\bar y_2 +\cdots + \lambda_n x_n\bar y_n$ would be better,  or $\mathbf u^\dagger H  \mathbf v$

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @DougM Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: @Mark Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: The second definition starts with a basis, and defines an inner product that makes the basis an orthonormal basis; the first definition starts with an inner product. Gram-Schmidt shows that given an inner product on a finite dimensional vector space you can find a basis for which the formula in your second definition holds (so def 1 yields def 2 for an appropriate basis). But def 1 is basis-independent; which despite your current preferences, is usually *much* better. Def 2 marries you to a specific basis; def 1 does not.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Definition 1 is much better for abstractly proving theorems, and definition 2 is much better for computational purposes. They are both worthwhile, but 2 is probably easier to derive from 1, and it is quite efficient to show that some example is an inner product using definition 1 rather than 2.

Comment: @Joppy Thank you very much for your comment.